# emulator in android studio avd extremely slow in Pop! _os

Tags: linux, flutter, android-studio, ubuntu, android-virtual-device

I recently installed the Linux Pop! _OS 20.04 LTS distribution to develop in flutter. Everything works very well, except the AVD emulator, which is extremely slow. What could it be?
I have a 16gb dell of ram, i5 8th generation and 256 of ssd.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this, I had to change quick boot to cold boot, as mentioned in [this redit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/rzz166/android_emulator_laggy_on_pop_os/). No idea why quick boot doesn't work, and my system was not spiking in any way but the whole OS was completely unusable until I killed the emulator. I'm on Pop! OS 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

im on POP OS 21.10 (Intel® Pentium(R) Gold G5420 CPU @ 3.80GHz × 4, 8 single channel ram ), first i need to applied this following instruction https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration?utm_source=android-studio#vm-linux , for my use case(flutter) i increased the ram to 3gb and VM heap to 512mb , chose Hardware GLES 2.0 on graphics option, then it runs smoothly, if u are using genymotion u can increase the VRAM on virtual box.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v35Dj.png)